# Cutting back a carpet edge.

Tags: basement

I have a tile entrance at my walk in basement door that I want to make larger. If I cut back the carpet a couple feet will I have to restretch the carpet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You will need to remove the existing tack strip and put a new one at the new location of the edge of the carpet, and then stretch it down normally.